# Is it dangerous to expose a front-channel logout endpoint that does not require authentication?

Tags: openid-connect, same-site-cookies

I have several apps connected to a single Identity Provider, which allows a Single SignOn experience for our users, and requires also a Single LogOut one.

For the logout, any app will start the logout request, calling the Identity Provider, which in turn will use [front-channel logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html) to render in hidden iframes the logout URLs of all the connected applications.

However, since the session cookie is set as SameSite=Lax,it will not be sent in the call to the logout endpoint of each application. This forces this endpoint not to require authentication.

This brings me to the following questions:

1. Are these assumtions correct? Is there something wrong in that brief explanation?
2. Is having a logout endpoint that does not require authentication dangerous? If yes, what kind of attacks could happen?
3. How can those attacks be prevented or mitigated?

Comment: How does the logout endpoint know which session should end, if the session is not identified?

Comment: In the front-channel logout spec the session ID is an optional parameter. My interpretation (at least it works like this in my system) is that a single session can be open at a time in the browser, and since this mechanism uses the browser for calling the logout endpoint, the purpose of this endpoint is to close that single session.

Comment: There is only one session per browser, but many sessions on the server. So if a request reaches the logout endpoint on the server without a session cookie, how can the server know which of the many sessions to end? Or, in other words: from which browser is has been called?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen : The front-channel logout is made through the front-channel i.e. through the browser. The OpenID provider embeds an iframe to the Relying Party. The request is made by the browser which sends the user (session) cookies on the Relying Party to the Relying party. The Relying party can therefore know which session should be closed.

Comment: @ysdx, but the browser does _not_ send the session cookie if it is from a different site than the OpenID provider (third-party cookie).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, Yes, this is caused by third-part cookie protection. The third party cookie protection is indeed preventing the proper usage of OIDC Front Channel Logout in many cases: this is discussed in the spec: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html#ThirdPartyContent.

Comment: The OP was mentioning "SameSite=Lax" which might prevent the session cookie from being send as well but is a different issue. The iframe can avoid the "SameSite=Lax" issue by making a call to the same origin (redirect, fetch).

Answer (score 0):

The main risk is that a third party website could try to log you out of the relying party

Some possible impacts:

- This could be used to generate some kind of denial of service for the user: some third party website you are currently browsing-on could keep logging you out.
- There might a risk of data-loss: if the user is logged-out while entering/submitting data to the relying party, this data might be lost.
- For some application, if the user is logged-out just before submitting some data, this data might be published as anonymous data and be available to everyone.

Possible Mitigations:

**(1) Enforcing the usage of the `sid` parameter:** First of all, the relying party can register `frontchannel_logout_session_required:true` in order to announce that a `sid` must be included in the front-channel logout request and reject the request of the parameter is not used.

**(2) Checking the Referer:** The relying party could check the `Referer` header in the front-channel logout request and only proceed if this matches with the origin of the OpenID provider associated with the current user session. A problem is that this header is not guaranteed to be present.

**(3) Using  frame-ancestors:** On modern browsers, the relying party could use using [CSP frame ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) in order to reject requests which do not come from the OpenID provider. If the relying party supports multiple OpenID providers, it could use a dedicated front-channel logout URI for each relying party (eg. `/oidc/frontchannel_logout/{provider_id}`) and use different values of the `frame-ancestors` parameter in order to prevent a rogue OpenID provider to log the users of a second OpenID provider.

For (2) and (3), the relying party could as well check that `Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe` in order to protect, for example, against open redirects in the OpenID provider.

A problem of (2) and (3) is that in the most general case there is no notion of "origin of the OpenID provider", the OpenID provider can technically embed the front-channel logout iframe from an origin which does not match with the origin of the Open ID provider's authorization endpoint (and other OpenID provider's endpoints). In practice, I would expect that the origin which embeds the front-channel logout iframe will usually be same as the origin of Open ID provider's authorization endpoint.

> However, since the session cookie is set as SameSite=Lax,it will not be sent in the call to the logout endpoint of each application. This forces this endpoint not to require authentication.

What the relying party care about is the user session on the relying party. Even if this session cookie is not sent in the original request to the front-channel logout URI, this URI could generate a second (e.g. to `?second_request=1`) request which would include the session cookie.